# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith' when use pandas dataframe condition

Tags: python, pandas

The `info.csv` data likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time,latitude,longitude,mileage,other_vals,speed,upload_time_add_8hour,upload_time_year_month,car_id,car_type,car_num,marketer_name
1234567890123,2020-09-27 02:41:02+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0,,0,2020/9/27 10:41,202009,,,12,
17100000001,2020-09-27 02:41:01+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0,,0,2020/9/27 10:41,202009,,,12345,
17200000002,2020-09-25 13:46:38+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0,,0,2020/9/25 21:46,202009,,,123456,
14111111111,2020-09-25 11:18:54+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0,,0,2020/9/25 19:18,202009,,,12121212,
57c1e18249727a0b,2020-09-25 11:18:42+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0,,0,2020/9/25 19:18,202009,,,,
57c1e18249727a0b,2020-09-23 10:16:55+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0.055559317,,0,2020/9/23 18:16,202009,,,,
57c1e18249727a0b,2020-09-23 10:16:15+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0.055559317,,0,2020/9/23 18:16,202009,,,,
57c1e18249727a0b,2020-09-23 10:15:35+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0.055559317,,0,2020/9/23 18:15,202009,,,,
57c1e18249727a0b,2020-09-23 10:15:04+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0.055559317,,0,2020/9/23 18:15,202009,,,,
57c1e18249727a0b,2020-09-23 10:14:55+00:00,38.01946,114.425888,0.055559317,,3.304916399,2020/9/23 18:14,202009,,,,
```

I use this code to split dataframe to sub-dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'info.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df_1 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len) !=11]
df_2 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11 & df['device_id'].astype(str).startswith('17')]#device_id start with 17
df_3 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11 & ~df['device_id'].astype(str).startswith('17')] #device_id doesn't start with 17
df = df[pd.notnull(df['car_num'])] 
print(len(df_1))
print(len(df_2))
print(len(df_3))
```

But the error message is:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.str.startswith`:

```
df_2 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11 & df['device_id'].astype(str).str.startswith('17')]#device_id start with 17
```

All together - you can avoid casting to string for each condition, you can assign output to helper variables:

```
s = df['device_id'].astype(str)
lens = s.str.len()

df_1 = df[(lens!=11)]
df_2 = df[(lens==11) & s.str.startswith('17')]#device_id start with 17
df_3 = df[(lens==11) & ~s.str.startswith('17')] #device_id doesn't start with 17
df = df[df['car_num'].notna()]
```

Comment: Hi,what about device_id doesn't start with 17?

Comment: @CR7 - Same way. Working for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Series do not have an attribute called `startswith`.
According to the [pandas startswith documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) it should be `Pandas.Series.str.startswith`.

Instead of using `.startswith('17')`, use `.str.startswith('17')`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'info.csv', encoding = "utf-8")
df_1 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len) !=11]
df_2 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11 & df['device_id'].astype(str).str.startswith('17')]#device_id start with 17
df_3 = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11 & ~df['device_id'].astype(str).str.startswith('17')] #device_id doesn't start with 17
df = df[pd.notnull(df['car_num'])] 
print(len(df_1))
print(len(df_2))
print(len(df_3))
```